# Ajax Parameter Being Received as {string[0[} in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

First of all, I have never successfully built an AJAX call that worked.  This is my first real try at doing this.

I am working on building a function to update existing records in a SQL database.  I am using ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) MVC but I also use JavaScript and jQuery.  I cannot have the page refresh, so I need to use ajax to contact the Controller and update the records.

I have an array that was converted from a NodeList.  When I debug step by step, the collectionsArray looks perfectly fine and has data in it.

```
//Create array based on the collections list
    const collectionsArray = Array.from(collectionList);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Collections/UpdateCollectionSortOrder',
        data: collectionsArray,
    })
        .done(function (msg) {
            alert('Sent');
        });
```

However, when I run the application and debug the code, the array is received in the Controller as {string[0]}.

Here is the method which is in the Controller, with my mouse hovered over the parameter:

[image]

Do not pay attention to the rest of the code in the controller method.  I have not really written anything in there of importance yet.  I plan to do that once the data is correctly transferred to the Controller.

I have tried dozens of ideas including what you see in the Controller with the serialize function, just to see if it processes the junk data that is getting passed, but it hasn't made a difference.

I have been Googling the issue & reading other StackOverflow posts.  I've tried things like adding/changing contentType, dataType, adding '`traditional: true`', using JSON.stringify, putting '`data: { collections: collectionsArray }`' in a dozen different formats.  I tried processing it as a GET instead of POST, I tried using params.

I am out of ideas.  Things that have worked for others are not working for me.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it's something minor.

UPDATE:  Here is the code which explains what the collectionList object is:

```
//Re-assign SortID's via each row's ID value
    var collectionList = document.querySelectorAll(".collection-row");

    for (var i = 1; i <= collectionList.length; i++) {
        collectionList[i - 1].setAttribute('id', i);
    }
```

What I am doing is getting a list off the screen and then re-assigning the ID value, because the point of this screen is to change the sort order of the list.  So I'm using the ID field to update the sort order, and then I plan to pass the new IDs and names to the DB, once I can get the array to pass through.

UPDATE:  SOLVED!
I want to post this follow up in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.
Thanks to @freedomn-m for their guidance!

So I took the NodeList object (collectionList) and converted it to a 2-dimensional array, pulling out only the fields I need, and then I passed that array onto the controller.  My previous efforts were causing me to push all sorts of junk that was not being understood by the system.

```
//Create a 2-dimensional array based on the collections list
    const collectionArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < collectionList.length; i++) {
        collectionArray.push([collectionList[i].id, collectionList[i].children[1].innerHTML]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Collections/UpdateCollectionSortOrder',
        data: { collections: collectionArray }
    })
        .done(function (msg) {
            alert('Sent');
        });
```

2-d array is coming through to the Controller successfully
[image]

Comment: Step 1) remove all parameters and get a basic POST to work.  Step 2) pass a *single* string from the ajax with corresponding single string parameter - ensure the `data { name: "test" }` matches the parameter `(string name)` - check that that works.  Use something like Postman to build a request that works for your end point, then configure ajax to send the request in that format.

Comment: It's unclear what `collectionList` is - you say a NodeList, but that's not a string array; you probably need t get the `.value`/`.val()` from the nodes.

Comment: Check the browser network tab to see exactly what's being sent after jquery has processed it.

Comment: @freedomn-m THANK YOU for getting back to me so quickly.  I performed the steps in your first comment and was able to successfully pass "test" to the Controller which is great news.  I'll work on your second suggestion with the NodeList/array situation.  I'll update my original post to include the code that explains what collectionList actually is.

Comment: All good now, thanks again.  I have been struggling with this issue for two days now.  Can you add an "answer" containing your first two comments and I can mark it as answered?  Sorry I'm not 100% sure how this works lol